# LINQ method and the order to use OrderBy() , Take() , and ToList()

Tags: linq

I just realized that my LINQ methods aren't doing anything at all what I thought they were.

```
HighestRatedBooks = allBooks.OrderByDescending(b => b.Review.Rating).Take(5).ToList();
```

The above query doesn't get the top 5 highest rated books, but rather 5 seemingly random books.

What would the correct query look like?

Right now this is returning books that don't even *have* a rating, much less a high one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is ordered correctly; what are the `Review` and `Rating` types?

Comment: OK, all I need is to exclude the null Review objects.